# jQuery: Attach Tooltip to Mouse Cursor Position Using Plugin Tipsy

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, hover, tooltip

I've been using an old jQuery plugin called [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).  I like the way the tooltips look and for the most part I like the plugin.  Unfortunately it only shows tooltips relative to the element it is retrieving the tooltip from.  I'd like to show the tooltip in the position of the mouse cursor instead.  Is there any way to do this?  I would personally like to use this tooltip plugin if at all possible.

I have tried playing with the plugin for a little while, but the code is beyond my current knowledge of jQuery.  I thought trying to capture the event when firing the 'show' function would let me get the coordinates where the event was fired but that didn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'll show the source JS file below:

```
// tipsy, facebook style tooltips for jquery
// version 1.0.0a
// (c) 2008-2010 jason frame [jason@onehackoranother.com]
// releated under the MIT license

(function($) {

function fixTitle($ele) {
    if ($ele.attr('title') || typeof($ele.attr('original-title')) != 'string') {
        $ele.attr('original-title', $ele.attr('title') || '').removeAttr('title');
    }
}

function Tipsy(element, options) {
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.options = options;
    this.enabled = true;
    fixTitle(this.$element);
}

Tipsy.prototype = {
    show: function() {
        var title = this.getTitle();
        if (title && this.enabled) {
            var $tip = this.tip();

            $tip.find('.tipsy-inner')[this.options.html ? 'html' : 'text'](title);
            $tip[0].className = 'tipsy'; // reset classname in case of dynamic gravity
            $tip.remove().css({top: 0, left: 0, visibility: 'hidden', display: 'block'}).appendTo(document.body);

            var pos = $.extend({}, this.$element.offset(), {
                width: this.$element[0].offsetWidth,
                height: this.$element[0].offsetHeight
            });

            var actualWidth = $tip[0].offsetWidth, actualHeight = $tip[0].offsetHeight;
            var gravity = (typeof this.options.gravity == 'function')
                            ? this.options.gravity.call(this.$element[0])
                            : this.options.gravity;

            var tp;
            switch (gravity.charAt(0)) {
                case 'n':
                    tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height + this.options.offset, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2};
                    break;
                case 's':
                    tp = {top: pos.top - actualHeight - this.options.offset, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2};
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left - actualWidth - this.options.offset};
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left + pos.width + this.options.offset};
                    break;
            }

            if (gravity.length == 2) {
                if (gravity.charAt(1) == 'w') {
                    tp.left = pos.left + pos.width / 2 - 15;
                } else {
                    tp.left = pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth + 15;
                }
            }

            $tip.css(tp).addClass('tipsy-' + gravity);

            if (this.options.fade) {
                $tip.stop().css({opacity: 0, display: 'block', visibility: 'visible'}).animate({opacity: this.options.opacity});
            } else {
                $tip.css({visibility: 'visible', opacity: this.options.opacity});
            }
        }
    },

    hide: function() {
        if (this.options.fade) {
            this.tip().stop().fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove(); });
        } else {
            this.tip().remove();
        }
    },

    getTitle: function() {
        var title, $e = this.$element, o = this.options;
        fixTitle($e);
        var title, o = this.options;
        if (typeof o.title == 'string') {
            title = $e.attr(o.title == 'title' ? 'original-title' : o.title);
        } else if (typeof o.title == 'function') {
            title = o.title.call($e[0]);
        }
        title = ('' + title).replace(/(^\s*|\s*$)/, "");
        return title || o.fallback;
    },

    tip: function() {
        if (!this.$tip) {
            this.$tip = $('<div class="tipsy"></div>').html('<div class="tipsy-arrow"></div><div class="tipsy-inner"/></div>');
        }
        return this.$tip;
    },

    validate: function() {
        if (!this.$element[0].parentNode) {
            this.hide();
            this.$element = null;
            this.options = null;
        }
    },

    enable: function() { this.enabled = true; },
    disable: function() { this.enabled = false; },
    toggleEnabled: function() { this.enabled = !this.enabled; }
};

$.fn.tipsy = function(options) {

    if (options === true) {
        return this.data('tipsy');
    } else if (typeof options == 'string') {
        return this.data('tipsy')[options]();
    }

    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.tipsy.defaults, options);

    function get(ele) {
        var tipsy = $.data(ele, 'tipsy');
        if (!tipsy) {
            tipsy = new Tipsy(ele, $.fn.tipsy.elementOptions(ele, options));
            $.data(ele, 'tipsy', tipsy);
        }
        return tipsy;
    }

    function enter() {
        var tipsy = get(this);
        tipsy.hoverState = 'in';
        if (options.delayIn == 0) {
            tipsy.show();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() { if (tipsy.hoverState == 'in') tipsy.show(); }, options.delayIn);
        }
    };

    function leave() {
        var tipsy = get(this);
        tipsy.hoverState = 'out';
        if (options.delayOut == 0) {
            tipsy.hide();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() { if (tipsy.hoverState == 'out') tipsy.hide(); }, options.delayOut);
        }
    };

    if (!options.live) this.each(function() { get(this); });

    if (options.trigger != 'manual') {
        var binder   = options.live ? 'live' : 'bind',
            eventIn  = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseenter' : 'focus',
            eventOut = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'blur';
        this[binder](eventIn, enter)[binder](eventOut, leave);
    }

    return this;

};

$.fn.tipsy.defaults = {
    delayIn: 0,
    delayOut: 0,
    fade: false,
    fallback: '',
    gravity: 'n',
    html: false,
    live: false,
    offset: 0,
    opacity: 0.8,
    title: 'title',
    trigger: 'hover'
};

// Overwrite this method to provide options on a per-element basis.
// For example, you could store the gravity in a 'tipsy-gravity' attribute:
// return $.extend({}, options, {gravity: $(ele).attr('tipsy-gravity') || 'n' });
// (remember - do not modify 'options' in place!)
$.fn.tipsy.elementOptions = function(ele, options) {
    return $.metadata ? $.extend({}, options, $(ele).metadata()) : options;
};

$.fn.tipsy.autoNS = function() {
    return $(this).offset().top > ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2) ? 's' : 'n';
};

$.fn.tipsy.autoWE = function() {
    return $(this).offset().left > ($(document).scrollLeft() + $(window).width() / 2) ? 'e' : 'w';
};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not knew tipsy before, and could not find a place where a full package was downloadable. So took your code and found the CSS from the website, along with the arrow glyph to produce this demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/df108obx/**

I have made `//ANSWER` comments anywhere some code is added. I thought the best approach was to create a new `gravity` style "`x`", that places the tooltip with base from where the mouse was, when the tipsy is activated. So

1. Added a `mouse : {x: 0, y: 0}` object to default options
2. Now storing `(e)` mouse position in the `enter()` function
3. Added a `case 'x' :` in the gravity switch in the `show()` function

There is certainly room for improvement, but this may be a good skeleton for extending tipsy with new ways of showing itself.

Comment: This is awesome!  Thanks so much.  The only problem now is that if I hover over an item with a tooltip too close to the edge of the screen then it makes the tooltip display too small.  Is there a way to get around that?  Perhaps putting the tooltip below the cursor would help?

Comment: @Phillip, glad to hear it was useful for you. Thank you for accepting the answer. Yes, there is a lot of things lacking. Does not have time now but will return this evening or next morning. In the meanwhile, think about extracting the tooltip from bootstrap 2.3.x -> http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ it works like a charm and the third of the code (if you extract the tooltipcode only) almost similar to tipsy. If not, it would be a great idea to setup a github for tipsy. As I said, I could not find a download that worked.

Comment: Thanks.  Its not too big of an issue and for now I'm just using the normal gravity settings.  I will also try to play with things in my spare time.